# Laravel Telescope adding filter in production

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have Telescope ( https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/telescope ) installed on Laravel 6.x. In the Laravel app, the file `app/Providers/TelescopeServiceProvider.php` contains the `register()` method. The following code exists.

```
Telescope::filter(function (IncomingEntry $entry) {

        if ($this->app->isLocal()) {
            return true;
        }

        return $entry->isReportableException() ||
               $entry->isFailedRequest() ||
               $entry->isFailedJob() ||
               $entry->isScheduledTask() ||
               $entry->hasMonitoredTag();
    });
```

This tells me that if env = local, all entries are recorded by if the env = production then only failed jobs, reportable exception, failed requests etc are recorded. It is also mentioned on https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/telescope#filtering-entries

Does anyone know how to add filters to record Mails and Jobs in production?